# Get response status_code using flask python issue

Tags: python, api, flask

I would like to get response HTTP status_code for monitor services using flask python.

My code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, url_for, redirect, render_template, flash, Response, abort

import requests

res = requests.get('https://192.168.1.100:8000/token?api=API',verify=False)
app = Flask(__name__)
print(res.url) # your.domain/test/3/3

print(res.status_code) # 200

@app.route('/services')
def check_services():
   if request.method == "GET" or request.method == "POST": 
        if res.status_code == '201':
                result =  'Sucess HTTP.Status_code 201 - Service TOKEN is working fine [OK]'
               return render_template('services.html'), 201
#              result = '401 -- Service TOKEN is working fine - parameter is not correct'

        else:
#                abort(401)  
               return render_template('services401.html'),401
```

but my code didnot work right.

My expected result, it will be returned by seperate HTTP status code: 201 or 401 or 500 whatever which I define in `if` condition.

Any help apprecated !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The status codes are `int`, not `str`. So, check with `201`, not `'201'`.
Your code should be:

```
if request.method == "GET" or request.method == "POST": 
    if res.status_code == 201:
        # do what you want here
```

See below for details.

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get')
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> type(r.status_code)
<class 'int'>
```